# Parallel ForEach заморозка потока

Tags: c#, plinq

Нужна была параллельная обработка очереди, я её реализовал, но есть проблема в том, что в определенном месте обработчика мне нужно реализовать остановку потока на определённое время.

Запуск Parallel:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, Start);
```

Обработчик:

```
    private void Start(string param)
    {
        Class class = new class(param);
        class.Start();
    }


Class.Start   

    public void Start()
        {
            DownloadAll();
            //....
        }
```

И в методе `DownloadAll` мне нужно реализовать остановку потока на определенное время (задаётся программно). `Thread.Sleep`, как я понимаю, здесь не подходит. Прошу помощи, желательно с примером кода.

Comment: Почему `Thread.Sleep` не подходит?

Comment: Как я заметил в отладке, он не останавливает поток. Видимо, тормозит основной

Comment: Он тормозит текущий. но Parallel.ForEach не настолько глуп чтобы создавать новые потоки и не использовать изначальный. Потому он активно использует изначальный поток и вы его тормозите.

Comment: Thread.Sleep обязан останавливать поток. Не может быть, что он не работает, а вы это заметили первым. Проверяйте ещё раз, возможно, вне отладчика.

Comment: Это веселая особенность отладчика такая. Когда вы делаете шаг - отладчик ставит точку останова на следующую инструкцию и возобновляет работу программы. Но на эту точку останова может попасть уже другой поток. Потому-то вам и кажется, что `Thread.Sleep` не работает.

Comment: И чтобы не было веселой отладки устанавливайте ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 } при отладке и будет один поток без прыжков, а потом не забывайте убрать это.

Comment: Немного запутался среди ответов, но всё равно спасибо за быстрое реагирование.
По поводу отладчика я понял, но я делал так: в Parallel Options передавал параметр `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` и ставил ему значение `1`. 

Мне не совсем понятна следующая вещь: если я указываю Thread.Sleep, он тормозит основной (программы) поток или же поток, созданный Parallel ForEach?

Comment: Я же писал выше. Он тормозит текущий. Но Parallel.Foreach использует И тот поток с которого начался (это CPU-bound тулза) и если был основной UI поток, где и начался Parallel.Foreach, то UI поток будет использоваться внутри тоже. А при  MaxDegreeOfParallelism =1 вообще будет незачем дергать потоки из пула. Оберните все в Task.Run и тогда вы отвяжетесь от UI потока

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но если можно, пример кода, чтобы наглядно увидеть, как это реализовать в данном месте, чтобы я мог остановить поток, созданный Parallel.ForEach.